# Calling REST web service from HTML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jersey-1.0

```
package com.leadwinner;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  

@Path("ServiceProvider2")  
public class ServiceProvider2 {  
 @GET  
 @Path("/InchToFeet")  
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
  public String convertInchToFeet(@QueryParam("i") int i) {  

    int inch=i;  
    double feet = 0;  
    feet =(double) inch/12;  

    return "<InchToFeetService>"  
    + "<Inch>" + inch + "</Inch>"  
      + "<Feet>" + feet + "</Feet>"  
     + "</InchToFeetService>";  
  }  


}
```

The following URL returns a result as XML:

.../SampleRest/ServiceProvider2/InchToFeet?i=2

This is fine, though when I am trying to run HTML files using tomcat server, I get the error:

> webpage not found 404 html files not running in restful web services
>   using jersey

Answer (score 1):

In order to make html files also work, you should modify the web.xml file to map your Jersey Servlet only to the urls that it should handle (RESTful urls).

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            ...
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServiceProvider2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

More info [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Comment: `<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer </servlet-class>............`<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  ` I used like this